# Simplify the following code to a one-liner using Linq queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

There are two tables, User and Expense, with one-to-many relationship. Therefore, UserClass contains a navigation property of type ICollection<> named Expenses. What I want is to get all the users whose name is John and include only the expenses where the description of the expense is Lunch. Following is what I came up with. But I feel like there is a better way. I want to Convert this:

```
List<User> users = db.Users.Where(user => user.Name == "John").ToList();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                List<Expense> expenses = db.Expenses.Where(expense => expense.Description == "Lunch" && expense.AddedBy == user.Id).ToList();
                user.Expenses = expenses;
            }
```

to something like this:

```
List<User> users = db.Users.Where(user => user.Name == "John").Include(user => user.Expenses.Where(expence => expence.Description == "Lunch")).ToList();
```

but it throws the following exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.dll
>   The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

An SQL query of what I want would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[User] AS A 
INNER JOIN Expense AS B 
ON A.Id = B.AddedBy
WHERE A.Name = 'John' AND B.Description = 'Lunch'
```

Model:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkFD7.jpg)

PS: I'm new to Entity Framework

Thanks.

Comment: Show your model class

Comment: can you try to use Include method before where condition

Comment: I don't think you can `Include` *only some instances of navigation property* this way. `.Include(user => user.Expenses)` should work though

Comment: @mshwf i have added an image

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim still same

Comment: @Rafalon your solution will include all the expenses. I only need expenses which has 'Lunch' in its description field.

Comment: I know that, and this is why I didn't post an *answer*, but a *comment*. The syntax you used for `.Include` can not work with "classic" EntityFramework, but as ThierryV showed, you could use it with Entity Framework Plus (`.IncludeFilter(...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition is using the projection query.

```
db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "John")
            .Where(u => u.Expenses.Any(e => e.Description == "Lunch")
            .Select(u => new
            {
                u,
                Expenses= u.Expenses.Where(e => e.Description == "Lunch")
            });
```

A property called `u` is of type `User`, and it has all the expenses, the other property `Expenses` will have only those expenses which are generated for `Launch`

Or use [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

```
db.Users.Where(user => user.Name == "John")
   .IncludeFilter(user => user.Expenses.Where(e => e.Description == "Launch"));
```

Comment: `Expences` should be `Expenses`, you miss a `)` at the end, and `.Where` does **not** return a `bool`, right?

Comment: This will still include ***all*** expenses of users having at least one expense with `Description == "Lunch"`. I think OP wants only `"Lunch"` expenses in `"John"` users. (from question, emphasis mine: *"get all the users whose name is John and include **only** the expenses where the description of the expense is Lunch"*)

Comment: That EF+ thing is interesting, I'll +1 for that. Still `);` missing at the end though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: @ThierryV  Entity Framework Plus works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the transport of selected data from your Database to your local process is one of the slower parts of the query. Therefore it is good practice not to fetch more properties than you actually plan to use.

You want several `Users` with some or all of their `Expenses`. Every `User` has a primary key `Id`, every `Expense` has a foreign key `UserId` of which you are certain that it equals the `Id` of its `User`.

If you Fetch 1000 users, each with 1000 expenses, your method would transfer 1 million `UserIds` of which you already know the value. What a waste!

> Only use Include if you plan to change the fetched values. If not, use Select`

To select some properties of some `Users` with some of their `Expenses`:

```
var result = myDbContext.Users               // From the collection of all Users
    .Where(user => user.Name == ...)         // Select only those that have a name ...
    .Select(user => new                      // from every remaining user make one new object
    {
        // Select only the properties you actually plan to use:
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        Expenses = user.Expenses
            .Where(expense => expense.Description == ...)
            .Select(expense => new
            {
                 // again, select only the properties you plan to use
                 Id = expense.Id,   
                 Description = expense.Description,

                 // not needed, you know it equals user.Id:
                 // UserId = expense.UserId

                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Sometimes you really want `Users with their Expenses`, for instance you need to use them as a return value of your procedure. Even then use Select and fill the properties that will really be needed in your use case (or fill all of them)

```
var result = myDbContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.Name == ...)
    .Select(user => new User()
    {
        // Select only the properties you actually plan to use:
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        Expenses = user.Expenses
            .Where(expense => expense.Description == ...)
            .Select(expense => new Expense()
            {
                 // again, select only the properties you plan to use
                 Id = expense.Id,   
                 Description = expense.Description,
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

The disadvantage of this is that the layout of your database tables seep through your communication layers. If your database changes all callers need to change, even if they don't use the new changed properties. My advice would be to use classes that you want outside your data layer. This might lead to `UsersWithTheirAddresses` and `UsersWithTheirExpenses`, and maybe even `UsersWithTheirFoodExpenses`. If a User gets an extra column like `CountryCode`, then `UsersWithTheirExpenses` won't have to change.